# Raspberry Pi connect via WiFi, but not Ethernet

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, wireless, ethernet-port

I setup Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi Model 3B using Raspberry Pi Imager for Windows. While configuring, I setup Wifi and it works smoothly. However, when I plug the device into ethernet it doesn't connect. I don't get an IP from router, but the light for ethernet is turned on. The output of ifconfig -a is as follows:

```
eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 94  bytes 7952 (7.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 94  bytes 7952 (7.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.91  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2001:56a:f2d5:c500:ba27:ebff:fe83:215b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe83:215b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1525  bytes 357096 (357.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 234  bytes 33603 (33.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In short the eth0 interface is not negotiating an IP, even though wlan0 is doing that.

I can see the eth0 port is down. I can make it up and force a static IP. But the configuration gets reset every time the device reboots.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Pi connected to a Gigabit capable router with a suitable cable (8 wire CAT5/CAT6) then the Ethernet should be automatically connected.

I initially setup Raspberry Pi OS on my Pi4 with WiFi and as soon as I booted with an Ethernet cable it came up. There is no need to configure anything.

NOTE Raspberry Pi Imager is designed to setup Raspberry Pi OS - it is unclear what it may do to Ubuntu Server which is designed to work with Ethernet and does not support WiFi by default (although it may have changed since I last used it) - either way Ubuntu Server is setup quite differently from Raspberry Pi OS.

I suggest you try a fresh installation and configure it manually using the Ubuntu instructions.